# Segmentation Fault in C++ most probably in strtok operation

Tags: c++, char, strtok

I was writing a postfix evaluation program which could handle multiple digits. Therefore I first read the inputs to a character array, and split them to array of (character array). Whenever I run my program, it gives a segmentation error (g++ on Ubuntu 13.10)

Here's my function to split

```
int split(char str[], char *ret[]){
    int c=0;
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        //printf ("%s\n",pch);
        strcpy(ret[c], pch); c++;
        //cout<<ret[c];
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    return c;
}
```

And part of my `main()`

```
char* s;
s =  new char[200];
cout<<"Enter Postfix Expression:\n > ";
cin.getline(s,200);
char* st[200];
//int size=3;
int size = split(s, st); // < Is what I'm passing correct?
```

I could not understand why the segfault occurred. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Thanks to [yugnum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149981/yngum) for the answer. The following did the trick

```
...
ret[c] = new char[strlen(pch)];
strcpy(ret[c], pch); c++;
...
```

Comment: don't you think st definition and ret[] in split function should be multi-dimensional?

Comment: You never allocate the elements in `st`/`ret`. What's wrong with using `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Comment: strtok in c++? really?

Comment: @molbdnilo actually I was just learning C++ and haven't been upto STL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* st[200];
int size = split(s, st);

int split(char str[], char *ret[]){
  ...
  strcpy(ret[c], pch);
  ...
}
```

this is what is wrong, you just pass bunch of uninitialized pointers to strcpy while it requires pointer that points to valid allocated memory.

Comment: you can initialize them with `new char[]` or use `std::string`, and find a split function on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `st` as 2D array, so split function will return an array of split strings

For example:

```
char st[20][200]
```

and then:

```
int split(char str[], char *ret[][]){
```

So you'll have 20 of 200 byte char array.
But it's not safe at all, I suggest you considering something else like `vector` or `std::string`. Also you need to allocate your array before `strcpy`.

Then

```
strcpy(ret[c], pch);
```

with c as counter, will copy split new string to your char array.
But consider std::string, which is best choice

Comment: Thanks. Actually I wanted to make the array of (dynamic-lengthed character array)

Comment: @cipher, so you can use std::string, easiest way to go